# $I$-smoothness in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading in Chapter 10 of Matsumura's book about $I$-smoothness.

In the book, the autor defines this concept by the following universal property:

Let $A$ be a ring, $B$ an $A$-algebra and $I \subset B$ an ideal. We say that $B$ with $I$-topology is $I$-smooth over $A$ if, given

1. An $A$-algebra $C$
2. An ideal $N \subset C$ such that $N^2=0$
3. A continuous homomorphism of A-algebras $\phi: B \rightarrow C/N$, where $C/N$ has the discrete topology

then there exist an $A$-algebras homorphism $\varphi:B \rightarrow C$ that lift $\phi$.

Now, a notion of commutative algebra corresponds with something of deeply related with algebraic geometry very often.

There's a link in this case too?
Is the concept of $I$-smoothes somehow related with the concept of classical smoothness of a manifold?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the role of $I$ in the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but this reminded me of a certain relation with smoothness, which I now try to describe. Smooth varieties $X$ have the infinitesimal lifting property: maps $Y\to X$ (with $Y$ affine) extend to maps from infinitesimal thickenings of $Y$ (this is the square-zero condition).

Suppose $A=k$ is an algebraically closed field.

If your $k$-algebra $B$ is *smooth* over $k$, then the following property holds:

> **Infinitesimal Lifting Property**: For any morphism $f:Y=\textrm{Spec }R\to \textrm{Spec }B$ and every infinitesimal thickening $Y\subset Y'$, there exists a morphism $Y'\to \textrm{Spec }A$ lifting $f$.

Translated at the level of rings, this means: you have $k$-algebra maps $\phi:B\to R$ and a surjection $C\to R=C/N$ with square-zero kernel $N$. Then there is a map $\varphi:B\to C$ lifting $\phi$.

**Example** (of the converse being false): Let $B=k[x,y]/xy$ (not smooth over $k$), $C=k[t]/t^2$, $N=(t)\subset C$ (so that $R=k$), and consider the small extension
$$0\to (t)\to C\to R\to 0,$$ together with the map $\phi:B\to R$ sending $x\mapsto 0,y\mapsto 0$. Then there is no problem in lifting $\phi$ to a map $B\to C$: just send $x\mapsto at,\,y\mapsto bt$ for some $a,b\in k$.

This can probably be extended to arbitrary rings $A$, but it is not something I ever faced.

Comment: This works for any base scheme $Y$. This often times goes under the heading of "formally smooth". So that $X\to Y$ is smooth if $X_Y(A)\to X_Y(A/I)$ is surjective for all pairs $(A,I)$ with $I^2=0$ (i.e. it's formally smooth), and of finite presentation. If you change 'surjective' to 'injective' you get unramified, and if you change it to 'bijective' you get etale.

Comment: So that is what formally smooth means! Thank you, Alex!

Comment: No problem :) It's certainly very helpful in showing that moduli spaces are smooth, as I am sure you are well aware.